# Tomcat JSP(2.0) Document how to stop automaticly closing empty body tags with /> instead of </tagname>

Tags: jsp, tomcat

The question is.
If I use JSP Documents (or JSP 2.0) and If I put a TAG without a BODY it is automaticly closed I dont want that.

so If I have `<div id=....> </div>`
it is automaticly converted to `<div id=.../>`

How I can stop this ?

I am using tomcat is there any configuration about that ?

P.S. the reason to want to stop it is because it simply "messes" the JQuery stuffs that the designer company are using.

Comment: This is not the case. Tags are not closed like this in JSP, some other mechanism must be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should check the definition of the JspServlet in web.xml in tomcat's conf directory. There are parameters that such as trimSpaces that alter the output to save space.

Comment: No, there's nothing which causes the described output. There's some extra abstraction layer in between. This smells more like JSPX.